# If $b=\sin(40^\circ +\alpha)$ and $0^\circ\lt\alpha\lt45^\circ$, compute $\cos(70^\circ +\alpha)$ in terms of $b$

Tags: trigonometry

> The correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3(1-b^2)}-b)$

I wrote $\cos(70^\circ +\alpha)=\cos(30^\circ +40^\circ +\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(40^\circ +\alpha)-\frac{1}{2}b,$ this didn't work. Then expanded $\sin(40^\circ +\alpha)$ and $\cos(70^\circ +\alpha)$ in the hope of getting a hint. Still and all, I couldn't get the answer up above.

Comment: In your answer try substituting cos (40+a) with $\sqrt{1-b^2}$

Comment: @AtulMishra I forgot to write $-b$ in the answer. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos(70^{\circ}+ \alpha)=\cos(40^{\circ}+ \alpha+30^{\circ})=$$
$$\cos(40^{\circ}+ \alpha)\cos(30^{\circ})-\sin(40^{\circ}+ \alpha)\sin(30^{\circ})=$$
$$\sqrt{1-\sin(40^{\circ}+\alpha)^2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{b}{2}$$
$$=\sqrt{1-b^2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}- \frac{b}{2}$$